# conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0

Tags: android

I want to use  play services 8.4.0 in my project but its giving me error can anyone help ?I want to use  play services 8.4.0 in my project but its giving me error can anyone help ?

app.gradle

```
                compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

project.gradle

```
               classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
                        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```